# Is it possible to make a dynamically allocated partition for Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, virtualbox, hard-drive

This may come across as a weird question. I find myself using Windows a lot more than Ubuntu as I game more than develop. I love having dual-boot setup where I can use both, but the only thing I hate is that I could set the partition for Ubuntu as only 100GB and either fill it up, or use hardly any of it, making it difficult to use a 1TB Hard Drive between 2 operating systems.

So, the real question is:
Can I set partition that can dynamically allocate space when running Ubuntu on it?

I'm thinking it would be similar to when you setup Ubuntu for example on VirtualBox and it asks for either a 'fixed size', or 'Dynamically located' hard disk. Picking the second option will fill up the more space you use. I think this feature, if it even exists or is possible would help my scenario out a lot. Any help or information is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: have you looked into Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?  if you just need ubuntu tools rather than the actual OS on baremetal it may be sufficient.

Comment: I really love using the OS as itself, it's fun for me to learn it and master it. I remember coming across for the first time was like discovering a whole new universe of computing lol. Thanks for the idea tho.

Comment: Id shrink the Ubuntu partition to say 20GB's. Linux OS are generally very tiny. You can do thr same for Windows, say 200GB. Then share one partition for documents between the two OS's. (Use NTFS) as windows wont like ext, but linux can handle any filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how partitions work in general - expanding Ubuntu partition is an operation which would require shrinking Windows partition, which may involve moving around files inside the NTFS filesystem on that partition so the whole process is quite involved.

There was that project which name escapes me which allowed to boot Ubuntu from a file on Windows' filesystem - this allowed to avoid doing any partitoning at all. Unlink VirtualBox you were able to boot into Ubuntu "for real". Unfortunately, the support for this installation method has been removed from Ubuntu for a while.

But you still can resize the partitions manually when you run out of space.

Comment: I was thinking it would be more of a work-around job. So, say I create a 100GB partition for Ubuntu and I fill it up, or need more space for windows. I can edit it without losing files or corrupting anything then?

Comment: You can boot from a flash drive and use GParted to shrink one partition and expand the other, yes. Provided that there is free space at the end of the partition you want to shrink.

Comment: I guess I'll just stick to that then, it's practically the same as what I wanted but I'm just going to have to do it manually. Thanks for the information, Sergey. I'll mark you as the answer.

Comment: I believe you are referring to [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).